# Is there a limit on the number of threads that can simultaneously acquire reader lock (SRW)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, mutex, thread-synchronization

In my application, for the concurrency, I am using Slim Reader Writer lock on Windows and pthread_rwlock_t on Mac/Linux.

I am seeing a weird test failure that makes me wonder if there is a limit on the number of threads that can possess the reader right at a given time ?

Please answer this for both SRW locks and pthread_rwlock_t . Thanks !

*Update*:

The test creates 16 threads initialized to call the same proc, let say foo().  This intermittently hangs.

```
void foo(int id)        //id is the thread ID
{
    /* Acquire shared mutex ... */
    AcquireReadLock(g_mutex);   // calls AcquireSRWLockShared on windows
    AtomicDecrement(&g_TotalNumberOfThreads); // calls InterLockedDecrement()
    while (g_TotalNumberOfThreads != 0)
        ;   //spin
    ReleaseReadLock(g_mutex);
}
```

Comment: what is the "weird test failure"? what is the premise, how does the test go and what are the results?

Comment: plus, practically, there is no limit.

Comment: @David, I updated the question with the answer to your comment.

Comment: show us the implementation of `AtomicDecrement`, `AcquireReadLock` and `ReleaseReadLock`

Comment: I do not understand why would someone down-vote this question. Can you please provide feedback. Thanks !

Comment: Hangs or spins mindlessly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the variable g_TotalNumberOfThreads (in the above code in the question) was being optimized by the compiler for not being read all the time.

Marking the variable g_TotalNumberOfThreads as volatile fixed the problem. Thanks !